# Checking if multiple string parameter values are empty in a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

If I have a C# method similar to

```
public void MyMethod(object myObject, string s1, string s2, string s3, ...)
{ ... }
```

and I needed to do a value check on the strings (if !string.IsNullOrEmpty(*var*)), instead of going through each variable, because there are quite a few of if checks, is there a more generic way I could accomplish this?

I was hoping to use ParameterInfo until I found you could not retrieve the Value of the parameter. My parameters will either be "" or have a value of a number (as a string) or true/false (as a string) -- these are going into a web.config, hence the string. The name of the method variable is the parameter name going into the web.config. I'm preventing writing of parameters that have null/empty values into the web.config, hence the IsNullOrEmpty check.

Right now what I have for each method parameter is below, just to give you an idea of format.

```
string name, value;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1))
{
 name = "s1";
 value = s1;
 /* do stuff */
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s2))
{
 name = "s2";
 value = s2;
 /* do stuff */
}
/* too many of these */
```

Comment: Why do you have `myObject`? Do you _just_ need to find an easier way to check for null or empty? In that case you could use `params string[] values` and iterate through them with a loop. What is `name` and `value` used for exactly?

Comment: The object is used for other purpose (identify the IIS web site) and the name/value is a key value pair for attributes in a web.config, but they both must be presented as a string in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

I think that would be better to pass instead of string1, string2, etc.. something like an array of strings (`string[]`).

This way you will be able to pass 2 arguments, or 10000, and you will not need to check, because in your array you will not include nulls if you want ;)

EDIT: Dictionary wins

```
public void MyMethod(object myObject, Dictionary<int, string> yourParams)
{ ... }
```

Comment: I wonder if something like this would work with a 2D array? On the submitting page, add "attributeName","attributeValue" (where the value is not null/empty).

Comment: mmmm, why a 2D array? why not a Dictionary? I think that would be easier with a Dictionary ;)